# I got reputation for editing my own answer?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing, reputation

I somehow got reputation for editing my own answer? It's [this edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/186962/revisions). Is this intentional or not? Because I could then edit some answers I've posted before, and get reputation, because edits to your own question won't have to be approved.

Comment: Are you sure the rep was for editing the answer and not, for example, someone removing an upvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You received 10 reputation for the single upvote (as of the time of writing this answer) on your answer. It may have looked like it came from the edit if the edit happened at the same time as the upvote, but rest assured that editing answers does not grant (or remove) reputation.